# Problems with HLS with some versions of Plutus Apps: INFO hie-bios: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/599'

Tags: plutus, git

I need some help with this problem.

With some version of Plutus Apps, HLS and VCode works perfect.
But with some specific versions, like this one:

```
commit cbc2df9e5d47d60505c28f321d75187d9ea85b07 (HEAD)
```

When HLS server starts, it throw and error with git from the Plutus Apps:

```
2022-11-09 17:18:26.921893854 [ThreadId 13] INFO hls:   Started LSP server in 0.00s
Couldn't load cradle (CradleNone)
2022-11-09 17:18:26.926139924 [ThreadId 13] INFO hls:   Registering ide configuration: IdeConfiguration {workspaceFolders = fromList [NormalizedUri 8157433327350195780 "file:///home/manuelpadilla/source/copyRepos/RATS-DAO/rats-dao-devs-staking-plutus-v2"], clientSettings = hashed Nothing}
2022-11-09 17:18:26.948609165 [ThreadId 69] INFO hls:   Consulting the cradle for "src/Validators/StakePlusV2/OffChain/EndPoints.hs"
2022-11-09 17:18:27.688350926 [ThreadId 111] INFO hie-bios: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/599': 'refs/remotes/origin/599/marconi-cli-list-index' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/599'
2022-11-09 17:18:27.689133924 [ThreadId 111] INFO hie-bios: From https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps
2022-11-09 17:18:27.68928638 [ThreadId 111] INFO hie-bios:   ! [new branch]          599        -> origin/599  (unable to update local ref)
```

Every else works fine, and I can build my project without problems.
But HLS is very helpful for coding and I appreciated a lot if I can use it.

This is a version of Plutus Apps that I can use reference scripts and Inline Datums.

I don't have this any of this issues with some previous versions neither.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Im editing this with something that fix that problem for me. I deleted the cache of hie-bios with:

```
cd $HOME/.cache/
sudo rm -R  hie-bios
```

Check more solutions here:

https://haskell-language-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html